# Set Nginx server_name as Server's IP pragmatically

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I currently have a Ruby on Rails application deployed in EC2 with auto scaling group, and I would like to access my application from server's IP.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ***.***.***.194;
}
```

I can access my app from the browser using the hardcoded IP.
But I would like the IP address to pragmatically set.

I tried using the `$server_addr`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name $server_addr;
}
```

But I'm seeing nginx's welcome page not my application.

Comment: Remove the `server_name` directive (it is not necessary) and remove the other `server` block that hosts the Nginx welcome page.